# Why is there no boost::date_time with microsec resolution on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, boost, time, boost-date-time

On `Win32` system `boost::date_time::microsec_clock()` is implemented using `ftime`, which provides only millisecond resolution: [Link to doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#ptime_from_clock)

There are some questions/answers on Stackoverflow stating this and linking the documentation, but not explaining why that is the case:

- [Stackoverflow #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735123/c-boost-calculate-time-spent-in-function)
- [Stackoverflow #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972221/measurement-with-boostposix-timemicrosec-clock-has-error-more-than-ten-micro)

There seemingly are ways to implement microsecond resolution on Windows:

- [GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Win8++)
- [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

What I'm interested in is why Boost implemented it that way, when in turn there are possibly solutions that would be more fitting?

Comment: There is [this](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4773) ticket on boost, where one comment states, that "resolution being addressable now is because even windows 7 professional does not manage or support control of threading on a microsecond level". This may be related, but I'm not sure (why I didn't posted it as definite answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` only became available with Windows 8 Desktop applications. It mimics Linuxes GetTimeOfDay. The implementation uses `QueryPerformanceCounter` to achieve the microsecond resolution. Timestamps are taken at the time of a system time increment. Subsequent calls to `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` will take the system time and add the elapsed "performance counter time" (elapsed ticks / performance counter frequency) as the high resolution part.

The functionallity of `QueryPerformanceCounter` again depends on platform specific details (HPET, ACPI PM timer, invariant TSC etc.). See [MSDN: Acquiring high-resolution time stamps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SO: Is QueryPerformanceFrequency acurate when using HPET?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22955902/1504523) for details. 
The various versions of Windows do have specific schemes to update the system time. Windows XP has a fixed file time granularty which is independent of the systems timer resolution. Only post Windows XP versions allow to modify the system time granularity by changing the system timer resolution.

This can be accomplished by means of the multimedia timer API `timeBeginPeriod` and/or the hidden API `NtSetTimerResolution` (See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22862989/1504523) for more details about using `
timeBeginPeriod and NtSetTimerResolution).

As stated, `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` is only available for desktop applications. The reason for this is the need for specific hardware.

---

*What I'm interested in is why Boost implemented it that way, when in turn there are possibly solutions that would be more fitting?*

**Taking the facts stated above will make the implementation very complex and the result very platform specific.** Every (!) Windows version has undergone severe changes of time keeping. Even the latest small step from 8 to 8.1 has changed the time keeping procedure considerably. However, there is still room to further improve time matters on Windows.

---

I should mention that `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` is, as of Windows 8.1, not giving results as accurate as expected or specified at [MSDN: GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It combines the system file time with the result of `QueryPerformanceCounter` to fill the gap between consecutive file time increments but it does not take system time adjustments into account. An active system time adjustement, e.g. done by `SetSystemTimeAdjustment`, modifies the system time granularity and the progress of the system time. However, the used performance counter frequency to build the result of `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` is kept constant. As a result, the microseconds part is off by the adjustment gain set by `SetSystemTimeAdjustment`.

Answer (score 5):

`QueryPerformanceCounter` can't help you on this problem. It gives you a timestamp, but as you don't know when the counter starts there is no reliable way to calculate an absolute time point out of it. boost::date_time is such a (user-understandable) time point.
The other difference is that a counter like QueryPerformanceCounter gives you a steadily increasing timer, while the system time can be influenced by the user and can therefore jump. 
So the 2 things are for different use cases. One for representing a real time, the other one for getting precise timing in the software and for benchmarking.

`GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` seems to fit the bill for a high resolution absolute time. I guess it wasn't used because it requires Windows8.